# using JOIN in the same table and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have this table

**tracking**

- id
- referer
- status
- session

i want to COUNT rows for the two tables (joined with itself)

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id), COUNT(t2.id)
FROM tracking t1
INNER JOIN tracking t2 on t2.session = t1.session AND t2.status = 2
WHERE t1.referer = 'http://google.com' AND t1.status = 1
```

with this data :

```
id | referer | status | session

1 | http://google.com | 1 | ABC

2 | ################# | 2 | ABC
```

i need to get (1,1) but im getting (1,null)

i tried with RIGHT JOIN but is not working either.

Comment: Try using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`..

Comment: returning 1,1 for me.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/487f2/1)

Comment: i added a new record to your sql fiddle (3, 'http://google.com', 1, 'CBA') and it still returns 1,1 and should be 2,1 (my initial question need to be updated) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3bda/1/0

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the task this code is supposed to perform? `INNER JOIN` can't possibly return different counts since you're filtering out any possible `NULL`s, so every row is getting counted for both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

## [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20fe5/1)

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id), COUNT(t2.id)
FROM tracking t1
LEFT JOIN tracking t2 on t2.session = t1.session AND t2.status = 2
WHERE t1.referer = 'http://google.com' AND t1.status = 1;
```

`t1` is the "left" table and `t2` is the "right" table. You want to use `LEFT JOIN` to make sure you get all the rows from the left table (`t1`), regardless of whether or not there is a match in the right table (`t2`).